# Interpolate perl's use command

Tags: perl

I am trying to dynamically call the use command by doing something like

```
   eval { use $modulename ;} ;
```

but the compiler complains about the syntax.  Is there an easy way of using the "use $modulename" only if needed ? As I want to determine which module to use depending on the user's input and interpolate the use `$modulename` dynamically.

Any input on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [How can I dynamically include Perl modules without using eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917261/how-can-i-dynamically-include-perl-modules-without-using-eval)

Comment: Something that the linked answers don't cover: `eval BLOCK` isn't "dynamic" or "interpolating" anything. Only `eval $string` does that.