# Access hash key of module whose module is not know till runtime

Tags: perl, hash

So I [figured out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13179359/3299282) how to load a module whose `$module_name` is not known till runtime.

Now, I wish to access a hash key, whose value happens to be a CODEREF.

```
my $hash_key = 'SOME_KEY';
my $code_ref = ${$module_name::hash}{$hash_key};
```

Then say:

```
$code_ref->(@args);
```

The `${$module_name::hash}{$hash_key}` is odd to me and I wonder if it works as intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. What you wrote won't work (`$module_name::hash` is the scalar variable `$hash` in the package `module_name`), but this will:

```
my $code_ref = ${$module_name . "::hash"}{$hash_key};
```

This kind of construction is ... discouraged, and prohibited under `use strict 'refs'`. I don't know what your use case is, but another approach to consider is to implement some common methods in your dynamically loaded modules.

```
my $code_ref = $module_name->getCode($hash_key);
$code_ref->(@args);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
${ $module_name . "::hash" }{$hash_key}
```

or

```
( $module_name . "::hash" )->{$hash_key}
```

Of course, you'll have to use `no strict qw( refs );` in the scope in which you do that.

```
my $hash = do { no strict qw( refs ); \%{ $module_name . "::hash" } };
$hash->{$hash_key}
```

Comment: Wtf? They were different.  Fixed

Comment: could/would `eval` help us in the TIMTOWTDI spirit?

Comment: That would be very heavy, and could require validation. It's not the approach I'd recommend, nor the one usually used.